# European Regulations and connecting leg of a Foreign flight booked on a single ticket

Tags: air-travel, europe, regulations, connecting-flights, compensation

Do European regulations of compensation apply when a connecting leg (that begins outside EU) of a flight (owned by a non-EU company) ticket bought online in European Union?

Example flight via connecting leg starting at Dubai, Doha, Istanbul, etc.

If yes, do they have to comply with the entire EU regulations?

(In above case the flight originates or terminates within EU)

Comment: Are we to assume a non-EU airline is providing the plane?

Comment: @origimbo corrected!

Answer (score 1):

The European Court of Justice said in [Wegener v. Royal Air Maroc, ECLI:EU:C:2018:361](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A62017CJ0537) earlier this year that the EU air passenger rights keep applying after a layover outside EU/EEA, when the entire journey was booked together.

This covers journeys that *originate* in the EU/EEA.

For journeys *towards* the EU/EEA, the EU air passenger rights only apply if the *airline* is based in the EU/EEA, which will rarely be the case for flights with a layover outside the area. This is independent of where the ticket was *bought*.

Comment: "if the airline is based in the EU/EEA": is that the operating airline?  The ticketing airline?  Either?  Something else?  (For example, consider a flight via Turkey to Germany on Turkish, but with a Lufthansa ticket, or on Lufthansa, but with a Turkish ticket.)

Comment: @phoog: The operating one, IIRC. I don't know what happens if a delay on a first leg operated by a non-EU airline causes a passenger to miss a second leg operated by an EU one.

Comment: Perhaps logic similar to that in *Wegener* would apply, but I have no idea whether a court has ruled on the question.